# Random distribution of points based on Perlin Noise?

Tags: algorithm, random, perlin-noise, noise-generator

Is there a good way to generate a random point in a 2D plane where the probability of choosing any specific location is based on Perlin Noise?

Essentially, when I generate a lot of points using such a method I would like to see many points in the areas where the Noise has high values and not so many in those where the value is lower.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple rejection-based approach:

1. Generate random point
2. Calculate Perlin noise value greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 1 at point
3. Generate random number greater than 0 and less than or equal to 1
4. If random number is greater than Perlin noise value then discard point and go back to step 1 and try again, otherwise that's your point

Comment: Ah this sounds cool. So… is my understanding correct that the “random” perlin noise value for any given point will always be the same (for the initial seed)? Just learning about peeling noise  so for any given point the probability it will be rejected is just the probability that the perlin noise value will be lower than any random number. So lower perlin areas will have higher probability of being rejected and so have fewer points.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct